# Spell checker and Mozilla Inspector open on their own when typing quickly

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox, libreoffice, spell-checking, gtkinspector

**Issue:** My typing is randomly interrupted by either the Spellchecker or the Inspector. The Spellchecker interrupts me if I'm using *any* word processor, including Libreoffice, Openoffice, Google Docs, and various note-taking apps. The Inspector happens on any web-browser.

This can happen multiple times a day.

**Background:** This has lasted about 5 , from Ubuntu 16 through 21, across multiple full-system resets, and through three keyboards. It's tremendously annoying, like having a pop-up ad that lives inside my computer. I've tried to fix it many times, but ultimately I cannot identify what the problem *is.* I don't understand what is going wrong or how, and that makes it hard to ask about.

The only thing this seems like it could be is a keyboard shortcut of some kind. The inspector opens with *CTRL + SHIFT + I*, but I can't possibly be hitting that by accident every few minutes, everyday. Also, there are tons of shortcuts, like *CTRL + SHIFT + G* which I have *never* triggered accidentally by typing.

Ideally I would like to understand what demon has been haunting me for all this time. However, I use these features *very* rarely, so I would be happy just disabling them entirely.

**Things That Don't Work**

1. Disabling these features directly through the settings menus. I've never found a setting that worked in 5 years.
2. Disabling these directly through Firefox's about:config. Nothing changed even after disabling everything containing the word "inspector" & "devtools." This is *differently* true for the spell-check.
3. Removing shortcuts using addons. There does not seem to be any way of doing this. In Firefox these shortcuts are privileged and can't be overridden. I have never found a program that would work for any word processor.
4. Changing shortcuts using addons fails for the same reason.

Laptop Model: System76 Gazelle

Comment: I can't replicate this and the fact that you have had the same problem over 5 different system installations suggests that it's something you're doing. You're probably right that it's a keyboard shortcut you are accidentally hitting. Review those and remove any shortcuts you don't need that seem related to what you're experiencing.

Comment: I would believe it is a shortcut of some key that you aren't expecting to have an effect... ironically, I just opened up the inspector with ALT+SHIFT+Q but it only happened that one time... Either way, F7 opens the spell check. Also hitting F10 opens up the context menu, if T is pressed it goes to the Tools dropdown, if S is pressed the spellcheck will be selected.  The 'menu key' (I really dont know whateverthehell it is called), but hitting that opens up the right-click menu and then hitting 'q' opens the inspector. And just F12 opens up the inspector as well... not just CTRL/SHIFT/I

Answer (score 0):

I added a dead shortcut at the system level. This is a bad solution for obvious reasons. The tradeoff is worth it in my case because I don't need these shortcuts, but they get tripped by accident a few times a day, every day, for *years*.

1. Find the keystroke that triggers the inspector. Ctrl + Shift + K, Ctrl + Shift + I, and Ctrl + Shift + C are the offenders in my case.
2. Go to Settings/Keyboard/Custom Shortcuts
3. Create a system shortcut for that combination. Under command, write "Nothing." Bam. Mozilla can't use them anymore.

EDIT: This actually hasn't stopped the problem. **Intentionally pressing and holding CTRL+SHIFT+C *does nothing,* and yet, Mozilla still opens the Inspector at random when I'm typing. It is not, and never was, the keyboard shortcut.**